# Sometimes the asp.net web application is not able to load the web.config

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I am facing a problem where sometimes the asp.net web application is not able to load the web.config.So what i am getting is an application level exception with an error message File does not exists.

I am not writing or editing the web.config at run-time from inside the code.

the web.config is put under inetpub/wwroot/webapp.....and when trying to update a record in a web form and for sometimes not always we are getting file does not exist application level exception .and when this error occurs in one form all forms stopped to connect to database.

we are resolving this problem by restarting the whole windows server 2008.

Will appreciate if you can provide with links or hint to try to resolve this issue.

Thanks,

Comment: can you give some more information so i can help ?

Comment: thanks,  information here : the normal web.config is put under inetpub/wwroot/webapp.....and when trying to access a web form and for sometimes not always we are getting file does not exist application level exception when trying to update a record.we are resolving this problem by restarting the whole windows server 2008.

Comment: As per i understand, reason... after enable system level feature some times you need to restart the server.anyway its good....like your problem is resolved.